# GCC not creating stack usage files despite using -fstack-usage

Tags: c, gcc

I'm attempting to enable `-fstack-usage` on a somewhat large build system and I can see that it's being passed to GCC correctly. However, when I check for `*.su` files after the build, they are not present.  I expect them to be placed in the same directory as where I've specified the object files to be.

Are there any conflicting GCC flags that can suppress the generation of these `*.su` files? I've read else where that `-flto` can do so, but I'm not using `-flto`

Comment: "I can see that it's being passed to GCC correctly." It would help us to help you if we could also see that.